# How can I get the substring of .net version instead of directly pointing the `net35` string in the `Install.ps1` script?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I need to set `CopyLocal` to `false` for each assembly of my NuGet package.
I do it in the `Install.ps1` file:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$asm_folder = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($installPath, "lib\\net35");

$files = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($asm_folder,"*.dll","TopDirectoryOnly");

$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file_name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file);
    $array.Add($file_name);
}

foreach ($reference in $project.Object.References) {

    if($array.Contains($reference.Name)) {

        if($reference.CopyLocal -eq $true) {
            $reference.CopyLocal = $false;
        }
        else {
            $reference.CopyLocal = $true;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the *substring* of .net version (of the target project) instead of directly pointing the `net35` string in the `Install.ps1` script?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read directories inside lib directory and see what other versions there. Like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $installPath -Recurse:$false -Filter 'net*' |?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Changed your script a little:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

#here you get the list of NET% folders
$net_folders = @(Get-ChildItem $installPath -Recurse:$false -Filter 'net*' |?{ $_.PSIsContainer })

#then you looking for every 'net' folder for .dll files
$files = @()
foreach ($net_folder in $net_folders){
   $files += @(Get-ChildItem $net_folders -Recurse:$false -Filter '*.dll' | Select @{l='FullName';e={[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.FullName)}}| Select -Expand FullName)
}

foreach ($reference in $project.Object.References) {
    if($files.Contains($reference.Name)) {
        #since you are setting copylocal to true anyway you wont need if/else statement
        $reference.CopyLocal = $true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I would like to look only that `net`-folder which is corresponding to the target project instead of iteration through all `net`-folders.

Comment: Replace `$reference.CopyLocal = $true;` to `$reference.CopyLocal = $false;`. Your code don't set `CopyLocal` fo `fals`e even this replacement was done.

Answer (score 0):

My decision isn't pleasant to me, but it works:

```
<#
Install.ps1
AutoCAD-YYYY.Net.* NuGet package.

© Andrey Bushman, 2016
https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Bush

This PowerShell script will be launched by NuGet each time when
this package will be installed into the Visual Studio project.

This script sets `CopyLocal` to `false` for each AutoCAD assembly.
#>
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$asm_root_folder_name = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($installPath,`
"lib");

$net_folders = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(`
$asm_root_folder_name, 'net*', 'TopDirectoryOnly');

$file_names = New-Object `
'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]';

foreach ($net in $net_folders) {

    $files = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($net,"*.dll"`
    ,"TopDirectoryOnly");

        foreach ($file in $files) {

            $file_name = [System.IO.Path]::`
            GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file);

            $file_names.Add($file_name);
    }
}

foreach ($reference in $project.Object.References) {

    if($file_names.Contains($reference.Name)) {

        $reference.CopyLocal = $false;
    }
}
```